# AxShockwaveFlash finished playing

Tags: windows, forms, axshockwaveflash

I'm writing a little app in C++ with Windows Forms and axShockwaveFlash object. Everything works fine, but on the end of the first video I want to play another automatically. Is there any way to find out, that the first video ended? I'm playing youtube videos.

Comment: You may want to give a little more information about the code your using.

Comment: Nothing complicated. Just some buttons and text area for link input, funcstion to parse link in right format, etc. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to find out if the video ended playing or not. If it generates event or if exists some function, which I can use.